# computer control of laser using TTL signal

Tags: matlab

I want to have a computer control of Microchip Nano Laser (355 manometer). I have operated manually this laser and it just needs 5 volt TTL signal through TTL generator. But I want to use computer to send 5 volt TTL signal to the laser to operate. Laser has a D sub 9 connector and I have attached it with the PC. So now what should i do to send 5 volt TTL to the laser.
Any programming or something else?
Thanks

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific in exactly what you are using and connecting to what. You seem to be suggesting you want to send 5v over the dsub from the pc, which is going to be quite hardware specific.

Comment: For laser operation I need to send 5 volt TTL signal from pc to laser (D sub 9 port). Problem is how can I generate this signal from pc and can send to the laser port.